# Grep showing file name and string found

Tags: grep

I need an egrep command that list all the file names that contains the words + which string it has found. Let's imagine this scenario:

Words that I need to find: `apple`, `watermelon` and `banana`.

What I need: I want to list all files that contains any of them (don't need to have all of them in the same file), and print which word it found in the file. Example of a search result I want:

```
./file1.txt:apple
./file1.txt:banana
./file2.txt:watermelon
./file5.txt:apple
```

I remember seeing a `grep` command which shows `FILENAME:STRING` in the search results, but I can't remember how it was done. I tried:

```
egrep -lr 'apple|banana|watermelon' .
```

But the search results showed:

```
./file1.txt
./file2.txt
```

Ok, it helps but ... in `file1`, which one of the words it found? That's the problem I'm facing .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do it with awk:

```
awk -v var1=apple -v var2=banana -v var3=watermelon '{ if($0~var1) {print FILENAME":"var1} ; if($0~var2) {print FILENAME":"var2} ; if($0~var3) {print FILENAME":"var3}  }' *
```

Basically, declare 3 variables, and 3 if statements to print filename and corresponding variable that has been found

**EDIT**

Shorter version:

`awk '/watermelon/{ print FILENAME":watermelon" }; /banana/{print FILENAME":banana"}; /apple/ {print FILENAME":apple"}' *`

Basic idea find `/regular expression/` and execute code in curly braces after it if found (which is to print FILENAME and which string we found ).

Comment: Thanks for the help :-),  but the result of it is just showing the file name, and not the word it found within this file.

Comment: @user2576376 I see , I thought you only wanted the filenames. I'll fix

Comment: Thanks @Serg, it worked like a charm! One last question: is there a way to filter the files it will look? Example: I want to find these 3 words in all files that the filename contains `*.doc` ... if it's not possible that's ok, I'll just remove the ones I don't want from the result :-)

Comment: @user2576376  .doc files somehow differ from simple text files, so just running a simple application like `grep` or `awk` on them wont work. They're encoded somehow that makes them binary files. So if I run `less somefile.doc` it asks permission to view it , since it may be binary file, and there's nothing but special characters there.

Comment: @user2576376 added a shorter version, please check

Comment: @Serg If it's docx, that's just XML in ZIP, so `zipgrep` could work. If it's doc... yea, that's binary and complex enough to be a minor filesystem.

Answer (score 15):

You used `-l`, which is the opposite of what you want. From [`man grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/grep.1.html):

```
-l, --files-with-matches
      Suppress normal output; instead print the  name  of  each  input
      file  from  which  output would normally have been printed.  The
      scanning will stop on the first  match.   (-l  is  specified  by
      POSIX.)
```

What you want is `-H`:

```
-H, --with-filename
      Print the file name for each match.  This is  the  default  when
      there is more than one file to search.
```

But that's the default anyway. Just do:

```
grep -Er 'apple|banana|watermelon' .
```

(The `-E` tells `grep` to act like `egrep`.)

Comment: Thanks! It's almost what I want ... using -Er, it's showing the Filename and the whole line with the word I want ... but I want to print just the word it found, not the whole line containing the word.

Comment: @user2576376 Just use `grep -Ero 'apple|banana|watermelon' .`

Comment: It returns "grep: illegal option -- o" ... I'm running these comands in an AIX server, tell me if there is any way to show you the version of the system or anything that could help you identify, I'm really a begginer on it.

Comment: @user2576376 Then you're asking this on the wrong site. Ask on [unix.se].

Answer (score 3):

Here is the command you're looking for:

```
grep -R "apple\|banana\|watermelon" <search_path>
```

The -R will read all files under each directory in *search_path*, recursively. The file name will be displayed for each match.

Comment: How can I execute this command in the current directory? I tried: `grep -R "apple\|banana\|watermelon" .`, but it did not return any result.

Answer (score 2):

The following will give you the output you want (using bash):

```
for x in apple banana watermelon ; do grep $x * ; done
```

The output will give you all lines containing the search string.

The following will give you only the search string as output:

```
for x in apple banana watermelon ; do grep -l $x * |xargs -I{} echo {}:$x; done
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it gives me the whole line content -->  `Filename:the fruit is apple`... what I need is, for example: `Filename:apple`

Comment: @sanjuro8998 I've edited the answer to give you only the search string as output